# Solr: How to show if searched keywords are matched or not?

Tags: java, solr, search-engine, solrj

I don´t want to highlight the searched keywords, I need just the information which keyword exists in a document.

My search looks like this: q=keyword1 OR keyword2 OR keyword3 OR keyword4

The result should look like this: Document A has keyword1 and keyword 3, Document B has keyword 3

I didn´t found an approach for this requirement. Should I parse manually a highlight snippet or are there others approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no out of the box way to Know what keywords matched the document.
The options are highlight, you would need to configure it to return all the search terms found.
You can also run debugQuery which will help return the matches for the documents.
Both of them are expensive operations.